# Need help with longtable

Tags: longtable

I'm trying to use the longtable package and need to do some changes in the final output.

1. Adjust the right margin. In my result, the right margin of my table is very close to the end of page. I don't want that
2. I need some vertical centering of the text inside the table.

I'm novice in latex and I don't have any idea on how to do those changes. I'd appreciate any help.

This is my code:

```
\section{PLAN DE TRABAJO}
\vspace{2cm}
El plan de trabajo estará fundamentado en la resolución secuencial de cada uno de los objetivos específicos planteados con anterioridad. Se estima una duración total de entre 16 semanas y se espera dedicar en general un  total de 4 a 6 semanas por objetivo.
\begin{longtable}{| p{.25\textwidth} | p{.25\textwidth}| p{.25\textwidth} | p{.25\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{Objetivo especifico}     & \textbf{Metas}     & \textbf{Indicador}             &\textbf{Actividades}\\ 
\hline
Realizar  el acopio de información, la caracterización de las actividades a realizar y la ingeniería básica de dichas actividades.         
&\begin{itemize}
    \item Documentar todas las actividades a realizar
    \item Realizar una descripción completa de las actividades realizando el levantamiento del problema 
    \item Diseñar la ingeniería básica requerida por cada una de las actividades 
\end{itemize}         
&
\begin{itemize}
\item Lista de revisión completada detallando la información recolectada.
\item Firma de minuta con el conjunto de actividades a realizar.
\item Cumplimiento de la normativa para la realización de ingeniería básica.
\item Cumplimiento de la normativa para la realización de ingeniería conceptual. 
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{enumerate}
\item Recolectar la documentación especificada en la lista de revisión (datasheets, planos, prospectos, etc.).
\item Hacer el levantamiento de la minuta donde se consignaran las actividades a realizar y se recibirá el aval por parte del Hospital Erasmo Meoz.
\item Ejecutar la ingeniería conceptual sobre cada una de las actividades de la lista.
\item Realizar la ingeniería básica sobre cada una de las actividades de la lista.

\end{enumerate}
\\ 
\hline
Diseñar la ingeniería de detalle de los compresores de lavandería y el sistema de iluminación de  los pasillos.
&
\begin{itemize}
    \item Determinar el sistema de control que se debe implementar en los compresores de lavandería.
    \item Proponer y justificar un esquema de iluminación optimo para las luces de pasillos y áreas comunes del primer piso del Hospital.
\end{itemize}
&
NOTA: Determinar indicador             
&
NOTA: Determinar actividades        
\\
\hline
    Actualizar los planes de mantenimiento de las calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras.
    &
    Verificar que el planes de mantenimiento vigente para calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras se encuentra actualizado y es el optimo. En caso contrario proponer un nuevo plan de mantenimiento, basado en ingeniería de confiabilidad, que se ajuste a estas condiciones.
    &
    NOTA: Determinar indicador             
    &
    NOTA: Determinar actividades         
    \\
    \hline
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}

\clearpage
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Objetivo especifico}     & \textbf{Metas}     & \textbf{Indicador}             &\textbf{Actividades}     \\ \hline
    Actualizar los planes de mantenimiento de las calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras.
    &
    Verificar que el planes de mantenimiento vigente para calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras se encuentra actualizado y es el optimo. En caso contrario proponer un nuevo plan de mantenimiento, basado en ingeniería de confiabilidad, que se ajuste a estas condiciones.
    &
    NOTA: Determinar indicador             
    &
    NOTA: Determinar actividades         
    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Plan de actividades, continuacion. \label{tab:table_label}}

\end{table}
```

And this is a capture of my output:

[image]

Also, when I add some space between the table and the text with `\vspace{}` or `\\`, something weird happens:

[image]

I don't understand why this does happens. Thank you all for your time

Comment: 4 columns with `0.25\textwidth` width and additional spacing (`\tabcolsep`) **must** be wider than the textwidth ;-)

Comment: try `0.21\textwidth`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table with one row per objective is probably not the way to do this. You get a ton of empty space in the first column, very narrow paragraphs on all columns, and burn up roughly one page per objective.

If it's going to take that much text to describe, consider instead regular sectioning commands (use the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package if you want to change their formatting instead of hard-coding `\vspace` commands, too).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{PLAN DE TRABAJO}

El plan de trabajo estará fundamentado en la resolución secuencial de cada
uno de los objetivos específicos planteados con anterioridad. Se estima una
duración total de entre 16 semanas y se espera dedicar en general un  total
de 4 a 6 semanas por objetivo.

\section{Some shorter summary of the objective}

Realizar el acopio de información, la caracterización de las
actividades a realizar y la ingeniería básica de dichas actividades.
\subsection{Metas}

\begin{itemize}
\item Documentar todas las actividades a realizar
\item Realizar una descripción completa de las actividades realizando
  el levantamiento del problema 
\item Diseñar la ingeniería básica requerida por cada una de las actividades
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Indicador}

\begin{itemize}
\item Lista de revisión completada detallando la información recolectada.
\item Firma de minuta con el conjunto de actividades a realizar.
\item Cumplimiento de la normativa para la realización de ingeniería básica.
\item Cumplimiento de la normativa para la realización de ingeniería
  conceptual.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Actividades}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Recolectar la documentación especificada en la lista de revisión
(datasheets, planos, prospectos, etc.).
\item Hacer el levantamiento de la minuta donde se consignaran las actividades
  a realizar y se recibirá el aval por parte del Hospital Erasmo Meoz.
\item Ejecutar la ingeniería conceptual sobre cada una de las actividades de
  la lista.
\item Realizar la ingeniería básica sobre cada una de las actividades de la
  lista.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right. Great answer Mr. Mike, I'm going to follow your advice

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a `longtable`, here is a way to do it, with the `enumitem`, `caption` and `makecell` packages. I define `tabitemize` and `tabenumerate` environments which have list parameters dapted for their inclusion in table cells

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, longtable, caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{2}
\newlist{tabenumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[tabitemize, 1,2]{label=\textbullet, leftmargin = 0.8em, topsep=0pt, itemsep=1pt, before =\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\RaggedRight}
\setlist[tabenumerate, 1,2]{label=\arabic*. , leftmargin=1.15em, topsep=0pt, itemsep=1pt, before =\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\RaggedRight}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}

\section{PLAN DE TRABAJO}
\vspace{2cm}
El plan de trabajo estará fundamentado en la resolución secuencial de cada uno de los objetivos específicos planteados con anterioridad. Se estima una duración total de entre 16 semanas y se espera dedicar en general un total de 4 a 6 semanas por objetivo.

\makegapedcells
\begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{0.22\linewidth}|}}%
  \hline
  \thead{Objetivo especifico} & \thead{Metas} & \thead{Indicador} & \thead{Actividades} \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  \captionsetup{position=below}
  \caption{Plan de actividades. \label{tab:table_label}}
  \endfoot
  \caption{Plan de actividades, continuacion. \label{tab:table_label}}
  \endlastfoot
  Realizar el acopio de información, la caracterización de las actividades a realizar y la ingeniería básica de dichas actividades.
  &\begin{tabitemize}
      \item Documentar todas las actividades a realizar
      \item Realizar una descripción completa de las actividades realizando el levantamiento del problema
      \item Diseñar la ingeniería básica requerida por cada una de las actividades
      \end{tabitemize}
  &
  \begin{tabitemize}
      \item Lista de revisión completada detallando la información recolectada.
      \item Firma de minuta con el conjunto de actividades a realizar.
      \item Cumplimiento de la normativa para la realización de ingeniería básica.
      \item Cumplimiento de la normativa para la realización de ingeniería conceptual.
  \end{tabitemize}
  &
  \begin{tabenumerate}
      \item Recolectar la documentación especificada en la lista de revisión (datasheets, planos, prospectos, etc.).
      \item Hacer el levantamiento de la minuta donde se consignaran las actividades a realizar y se recibirá el aval por parte del Hospital Erasmo Meoz.
      \item Ejecutar la ingeniería conceptual sobre cada una de las actividades de la lista.
      \item Realizar la ingeniería básica sobre cada una de las actividades de la lista.
  \end{tabenumerate}\\
  \hline
  Actualizar los planes de mantenimiento de las calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras.
  &
  Verificar que el planes de mantenimiento vigente para calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras se encuentra actualizado y es el optimo. En caso contrario proponer un nuevo plan de mantenimiento, basado en ingeniería de confiabilidad, que se ajuste a estas condiciones.
  &
  NOTA: Determinar indicador
  &
  NOTA: Determinar actividades \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bernard. I understand better the use of longtable

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to be useful.